# Is it possible to access the points in a Graphicspath?

Tags: c#, user-interface, drawing, gdi+

If there is a line added to a Graphicspath with two ends location defined, is it possible to read this pair of points?

```
Point[] myArray =
         {
             new Point(30,30),
             new Point(60,60),

         };
GraphicsPath myPath2 = new GraphicsPath();
myPath2.AddLines(myArray2);
```

from myPath2, is there something similar to `myPath2.Location` that can give me the points (30,30) and (60,60)?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible via [`GraphicsPath.PathPoints`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathpoints(v=vs.110).aspx)  but you will need to understand the 2nd array of [`GraphicsPath.PathTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathtypes(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Only if all the points are added as a simple point array of **line** coordinates, maybe like this:

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
..  // add some points!
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddLines(points.ToArray());
```

will you be able to use/modify the points without much hassle.

If you add them via **rounded** shapes, like..

```
 gp.AddEllipse(ClientRectangle);
```

..you will need to understand the various types! The same is true when you add them as other curves  `gp.AddCurves(points.ToArray());`

If you add them as `gp.AddRectangle(ClientRectangle);` you will get the regular points but with a byte type that says

> 0 - Indicates that the point is the start of a figure.

So in your case you get at the 1st of your points like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(gp.PathPoints[1].ToString());
```

Btw: There is no such thing as a `GraphicsPath.Location`; but you may find `GraphicsPath.GetBounds()` useful..

Note that all rounded shapes (including arcs and ellipses!) in fact consist only of bezier points:

> 3  - Indicates that the point is an endpoint or control point of a
>   cubic Bézier spline

which means that the `PathPoints` are **alternating** endpoints and control points.

Answer (score 0):

Somethimes, Matrix don't plot correct my points, so..., in small number of paths, this is helpfull, in this example you can: read, modify and compare, points and point types, rewrite your path or create a new.. etc ..

```
PointF[] changedPoints = Refpath.PathData.Points;
byte[] pointTypes = Refpath.PathData.Types;

List<PointF> OriginalPoints = new List<PointF>();
PointF currentPoint = new Point();
int MyCoffe = 0;

Refpath.PathPoints
        .ToList()
            .ForEach(
                i =>
                {    
                    currentPoint = new PointF
                    {
                        X = i.X,
                        Y = i.Y
                    };
                    OriginalPoints.Add(currentPoint);

                    if (pointTypes[MyCoffe]==3)
                    { 
                        // it's a curve, see the "TaW" explantion, do something, like add text caption, etc...
                        changedPoints[MyCoffe].X -= 100; 
                        changedPoints[MyCoffe].Y -= 100;
                        // etc...
                    }

                    changedPoints[MyCoffe].X += 100; // if you want to change value
                    changedPoints[MyCoffe].Y += 100;
                    MyCoffe ++;
                }
            );
GraphicsPath newPath = new GraphicsPath(changedPoints, pointTypes);
```