# System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.PathData documentation/examples

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I want to write a converter from [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) to a different format.

MSDN seems very terse on this topic and doesn't help to create a full picture - I can't be sure I can handle all point types correctly.

- [PathPointType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathpointtype),
- [GraphicsPath.PathTypes Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathtypes)

- both repeat approximately the same description, except it doesn't give the full picture to someone who are not familiar already with what it supposed to mean.

I can dump some time into reversing it from hand-crafted examples, but I can't estimate and justify the time for that and I'm not sure I can cover all cases.

Is there an article/example that is targeted for custom rendering of GraphicsPath rather than for consumer code and also goes into greater detail?

Comment: Agree, not covered in depth. Reading examples, source code, articles, books... helps you to draw the big picture yourself. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816242/14171304), [Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/understanding-and-using-graphics-paths-in-gdi/), [Book](https://books.google.com.kw/books/about/C_Graphics_Programming.html?id=QJ0XLsHgircC&redir_esc=y)....

Comment: You probably want to use the C++ documentation for this, it's much more complete. Since the use of most of the [PointTypes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusenums/ne-gdiplusenums-pathpointtype) is clear enough, I suggest to start with [GraphicsPath::SetMarker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdipluspath/nf-gdipluspath-graphicspath-setmarker), to understand what a Marker is, then use the [GraphicsPathIterator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdipluspath/nl-gdipluspath-graphicspathiterator) to enumerate the points and their type.

Comment: All these methods and the enumerator are available in .Net. The names of methods, properties and enumerators used are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I can see now that dash type is not used, marker is a flag that can be ignored for my purposes. Still can't see what masking is for.

Comment: A Mask is used to show or hide a Point. Can be set when a Region overlaps another. In overlapped Regions, Points can be Visible or not Visible (capitol V, in the general Path meaning). Masks hide all but the Point Type.

Comment: Now this is confusing, after I thought I've got it's purpose. The value 0x7 doesn't look like a flag and apparently it's just a convenience for binary operations (like `type & mask == besier`).